# OOP in javascript: the "this" scope changes when method is passed as a callback

Tags: javascript, oop, p5.js

I am coding a javascript program using a nice library called [p5](http://p5js.org).
I am trying to OOP in javascript, but I am having a problem with the scope of the pointer *this*.
Inside the constructor of my *BackgroungTools* class I define some class' members, as shown below:

```
BackgroundTools = function() {
        this.isBackgroundToolsOn = false

        this.backgroundButton = createButton('Background')
        this.backgroundButton.position(20,20)
        this.backgroundButton.mouseClicked(this.toggleBackgroundTools)

        this.backgroundSliderRed = createSlider(0,255)
        this.backgroundSliderRed.position(20,50)
        this.backgroundSliderRed.hide()
        console.log(this)
}

BackgroundTools.prototype.toggleBackgroundTools = function() {
    console.log(this)
    if (this.isBackgroundToolsOn) {
            this.backgroundSliderRed.hide()
            this.isBackgroundToolsOn = false
    } else {
            this.backgroundSliderRed.show()
            this.isBackgroundToolsOn = true
    }
}
```

Notice that *mouseClicked*, in the constructor, receives a method from the class as argument, it's a callback function.
Later, I then instantiate this class inside the *setup* function of p5:

```
function setup() {
    canvas = createCanvas(800,600)
    background(0)
    backgroundTools = new BackgroundTools()
}

function draw() {
}
```

When *this* is printed in the Constructor we get what is expected (a pointer to the current object). But when I click in the button and the method *toggleBackgroundTools* is called, the *this* inside it isn't what we expect to be: it isn't a pointer to the current object, but it's something that prints in the console this: `[top: Window[0], window: Window[0], location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…]`

I think that the method *mouseClicked* from p5.Element sort of change the scope of *this*. But I want to access the class' members in *toggleBackgroundTools* method.

Someone has went through this before?
Any ideas on how can I deal with this situation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you set up the event handler, instead of just passing `object.toggleBackgroundTools` as the function pass an anonymous function wrapped around a call to the function via the object reference. JavaScript objects don't work the same was as in other languages.

Comment: Try `this.backgroundButton.mouseClicked(this.toggleBackgroundTools.bind(this))`.

Comment: It did it, @LukeB.! I didn't know the method *bind*. (I'm new in OOP for javascript, coming from Java). Thanks a lot!

Also, thanks, @Pointy. I'll try your way too.

Comment: @jhow basically `.bind()` is a function that does what I described: it gives you a function that guarantees that the *real* function you want to call is called so that `this` has the right value.